# Switching between 2 fragments in the same activity without refreshing the data source

Tags: android

I have Fragment1 and Fragment2, RecyclerView1 corresponding to Fragment1, RecyclerView2 corresponding to Fragment2.
Both RecyclerViews have the same data source (the same information).

I use a button, let's say SwitchButton, to switch between the 2 fragments. Both fragments are in the same activity.

Use case: scrolling in RecyclerView1 to position 10, then clicking on the SwitchButton will show Fragment2 with the RecyclerView2 scrolled to position 10.

Where to keep the data? Because I don't want to make calls to server each time I switch between Fragment1 and Fragment2. Hope you understand. Thanks!

Comment: You are probably calling replace hence recreating the fragment hence recreating the recyclerView and its adapter, that has nothing to do with your network calls right?

Comment: use Interface keep your data in activity. your fragment  will be destroyed. but the data will be stored in activity variables. so when loading fragment check whether the data exist in activity first , if not get the data from network and save it to activity variable.

Comment: @Nanoc Thank you for your response. At first I thought that if I create an Abstract fragment which will be extended by Fragment1 and Fragment2 and do the network call there will keep the information, but it's stupid, because when I change from one fragment to another, the current fragment will be destroyed, then of course, I lose all the data. The comment below yours is the solution, to keep the data in the Activity, and if the Fragment1 or Fragment2 is destroyed, I would not lose the data. Thank you both, guys!

Comment: @HourGlass Thank you, this is the solution. I don't know why I didn't thought about it.

Comment: welcome always, can I submit it as answer? @sunlover3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the help of Interface.

1.create an interface with two methods one to set network call data and other to get the assigned network call data in activity.

2.In both fragments before making network call check whether the assigned data in activity using interface exist.

3. if it doesn't exist , make network call, save the data to activity variable.
4. when the fragment destroyed and recreated. the data will not be lost.