# How should a fragment listen for data from an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

in my Android app I have this class called "TripleTab2". TripleTab2 is a fragment that is called as part of a tabbed activity.

```
public class TripleTab2 extends Fragment {

private TextView nameAndNumberText;
private LinearLayout nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS;

private Map<String, String> nameToNumberMapping;
private View view;
private ArrayList<String> chosenSMSContacts;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assign_pattern_tab_2, container, false);
    nameAndNumberText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.numAndNameView);
    nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS);
    chosenSMSContacts = getArguments().getStringArrayList("numbersToMove");
    createTextViews();

    for(String chosenSMSContact : chosenSMSContacts){
        nameAndNumberText.append(chosenSMSContact);
    }

    return view;
}
```

The following line of code causes a problem **(NullPointerException)**:

```
chosenSMSContacts = getArguments().getStringArrayList("numbersToMove");
        createTextViews();
```

Actually, that makes sense, because the actvity-class called `"ChooseSMSContactActivity"` (which sends this data) is called after the `tripleTab2-class`.

Here it is:

```
public class ChooseSMSContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS;
private Map<String, String> nameToNumberMapping;
private Button selectedNumberBtn;
private ArrayList<String> selectedNamesAndNumbers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_smscontact_to_add);

    nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dropDownMenuLayout);
    selectedNumberBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectedNumberBtn);
    createCheckboxes();
    selectedNamesAndNumbers = new ArrayList<>();


    selectedNumberBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for(int i=0; i < nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS.getChildCount(); i++){
                if(nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox){
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS.getChildAt(i);

                    if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                        selectedNamesAndNumbers.add(checkBox.getText().toString());
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putStringArrayList("numbersToMove", selectedNamesAndNumbers);
                        TripleTab2 tripleTab2 = new TripleTab2();
                        tripleTab2.setArguments(bundle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });


}
```

So, TripleTab2 does not have this data on creation, because it is called before `ChooseSMSContactActivity`.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this problem? Should I use a BroadcastReceiver or something like that?

Comment: Just checking in, you are creating the TripleTab2 class and passing the bundle, however you aren't doing anything with your `tripleTab2` object. It just sits there. You need to display that specific object in your activity. I'm guessing you create the fragment through XML right now?

Comment: The `NullPointerException` is due to not creating an instance of chosenSMSContacts. You have to initiate the instance then used it otherwise NullPointerException will be prompt.

Comment: You know the cause of problem.What exactly you want to achieve here. You can also use startActivityForResult() which will return the result back to your `tab2 fragment.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970790/fragment-getarguments-returns-null

Comment: I suggest using the fragment factory method to create the instance of the Fragment. You can check the `Include fragment factory methods?` option when creating Fragment in Android Studio. It will generate a template  for you.

Comment: You are passing a value via bundle why not you just pass the value in construtor while creating your instance `TripleTab2 tripleTab2 = new TripleTab2();`

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions! I will try them out now

Comment: You can use a ViewModel in Activity and then the fragments can observe the LiveData from ViewModelProvider of Activity in the Fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to pass data from activity to fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137017/android-how-to-pass-data-from-activity-to-fragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the EventBus-library.

In TripleTab2 EventBus was registered, and an onEvent-method was created:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

@Subscribe
public void onEvent(CustomMessageEvent event){
    TextView nameAndNum = new TextView(view.getContext());
    nameAndNum.append(event.getCustomMessage());
    nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS.addView(nameAndNum);
}
```

The CustomMessageEvent-class looks like this:

```
public class CustomMessageEvent {

private String customMessage;

public String getCustomMessage() {
    return customMessage;
}

public void setCustomMessage(String customMessage) {
    this.customMessage = customMessage;
}
```

In the button onClickListener in ChooseSMSActivity I added an EventBus event:

```
selectedNumberBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for(int i=0; i < nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS.getChildCount(); i++){
                if(nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox){
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) nameAndNumbersLayoutSMS.getChildAt(i);

                    if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                        selectedNamesAndNumbers.add(checkBox.getText().toString());
                        CustomMessageEvent event = new CustomMessageEvent();
                        event.setCustomMessage(checkBox.getText().toString());
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```